# No routes matched location after using useParams

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Hello so i want to send my state(user email) after use logged in to home page and want to display the email. But after redirecting to home page with login button i got an error `No routes matched location "/home/"`. But if i input the route manualy localhost:3000/home/example.com, its worked perfectly fine. How do you fix this error.

**index.js**

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Register />} />
      <Route path="/home/:email" element={<App />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

**login.js**

```
const Login = () => {

  let navigate = useNavigate();

  const [emailLog, setEmailLog] = useState("");
  const [passwordLog, setPasswordLog] = useState("");

  const [loginStatus, setLoginStatus] = useState("");

  Axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;


  const login = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/login" , {
      email: emailLog, 
      password: passwordLog
    }).then((response)=> {
      console.log(response)

      if(response.data.message) {
        alert((response.data.message))
      } else {
        navigate(`/home/${loginStatus}`)
        setLoginStatus(response.data[0].email)
      }
    })
  }

  const toHome = () => {
    navigate("/home")
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/login').then((response)=> {
      if(response.data.loggedIn == true) {
        setLoginStatus(response.data.email[0].email)
      }
    })
  })
 
  return (
    <div>
    <img className="wave" src={Wave} />
    <div className="wrapper">
      
        <div className="img">
            <img src={Background}/>
        </div>

        <div className="register-content">
        <div className='registerForm'>
                <img src={Avatar} />
                <h2 className="title">Welcome</h2>
                <div className="input-div one">
                   <div className="i">
                        <i className="fas fa-user"><GrMail /></i>
                   </div>
                   <div className="div">
                        <input type="email" className="input" placeholder='Email' required 
                    onChange={(e)=> {
                      setEmailLog(e.target.value)
                    }}/>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div className="input-div pass">
                   <div className="i"> 
                        <i className="fas fa-lock"><AiFillLock /></i>
                   </div>
                   <div className="div">
                        <input type="password" className="input" placeholder='Password' required
                    onChange={(e)=> {
                      setPasswordLog(e.target.value)
                    }}/>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <a href="/">Don't have an account ?</a>
              <button  type='submit' className='btn' onClick={login}>Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> 
  )
}

export default Login
```

**app.js**

```
 const {email} = useParams();
<div className="App">
     <BasicExample />
    <div className='formInput'>
      <form method='POST' encType='multipart/form-data' action='http://localhost:3001/upload'>
     <div className='textUser'>
      <h1>{email}</h1>
     </div>
          
          <input className='inputForm' type="email" placeholder='Email' name='email'  />
          

          <input className='inputForm'  type="number" placeholder='Invoice No' name='Invoice_No'  />

        
          <input className='inputForm'  type="date" placeholder='Date and Time' name='Invoice_Date'  />

        
          <select className='selectBox' name='Curr' onChange={(e)=> {
            setCurrency(e.target.value);
          }}>
            <option value="IDR">IDR</option>
            <option value="USD">USD</option>
            <option value="YEN">YEN</option>
          </select>

         
          <input className='inputForm'  type="number" placeholder='Amount' name='Amount'/>

     
          <input className='inputForm'  type="text" placeholder='Supplier' name='Supplier' />
          
         
          <input  className='custom-file-upload' type="file" name="DocumentFile" />
          
         

          <button className='btnSubmit'>Submit</button>
      </form>

    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

in the login Function change

```
if(response.data.message) {
   alert((response.data.message))
} else {
   navigate(`/home/${loginStatus}`)
   setLoginStatus(response.data[0].email)
}
```

to

```
if(response.data.message) {
   alert((response.data.message))
} else {
   setLoginStatus(response.data[0].email)
   navigate(`/home/${loginStatus}`)
}
```

The code reads from top to buttom. You did not set the `loginStatus` first but you used it, so the value of it is `undefined`. In order to work, you have to set the value to it first then use it

Comment: Please add a brief explanation why it needs to be changed

Comment: The code reads from top to buttom. You did not set the `loginStatus` first but you used it, so the value of it is `undefined`. In order to work, you have to set the value to it first then use it

Comment: Please click on edit ln your answer and append it to ir :) rather than leaving as a comment :)